# Free Heap memory in C

Tags: c, macos, heap-memory

Is there a way to get the free heap memory at runtime in C on macOS?
I found this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
    struct rusage usage;

    // Get the current resource usage
    if (getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage) == -1) {
        perror("getrusage");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Free heap memory: %ld bytes\n", usage.ru_maxrss);

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is what I'm searching for.

Another suggestion I found is to use `malloc_size(NULL)`, it says that `NULL` argument tells `malloc_size()` to return the size of the free space in the heap, could it be true?

Comment: Does reading `/proc/meminfo` help? `cat /proc/meminfo` prints that info on Linux, haven't tested on MacOS.

Comment: It seems to be unuseful, it returns: cat: /proc/meminfo: No such file or directory

Comment: Parse the output of [vm_stat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems)?

Comment: which line tells me the amount of free heap memory?

Comment: `malloc_size()` is not part of standard C, nor is it specified by POSIX.  It seems to be a BSD thing, which MacOS (therefore) inherited.  I don't see any recent documentation for it, so I'm unsure whether it still exists in recent MacOS.  [The documentation I did find](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/malloc_size.3.html) does not specify behavior for `malloc_size(NULL)`, so it would be unwise to assume that such a call will succeed at all, and if it does, to attribute any particular significance to the result.